# How can I access Google+ user's email and pictures address through OWIN in ASP.NET 4.5 C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, google-plus

I am trying to SSO with google using the out of the box capabilities of OWIN in ASP.NET 4.5 web forms. I can successfully associate a login with a google account but I only get the username. I need the user's email address and their photo to generate an avatar. Do I need access to their Google+ account?

Anyone managed to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Could you show us some code or a link to an API that shows how you are getting the username?

Comment: It's actually extremely easy. Follow these instructions: [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services)

Comment: google authentication is disabled. You need to use google+ https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/csharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally don't know in details how OWIN performs authentication against Google+, but I know that to get the email address, your application should also explicitly request permission to **email** scope.

See https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth for the scopes description